# Como pegar o mês formatado com zero à esquerda no Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, data

Estou tentando pegar o mês no TypeScript com Node.js:

```
const today = new Date();
var todayMonth = today.getMonth() + 1
if(todayMonth < 10) {
  todayMonth = '0' + todayMonth
}
```

Mas estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> "O tipo 'string' não pode ser atribuído ao tipo 'number'.ts(2322)."

Como eu poderia fazer colocar o zero na frente se o mês for menor que 10, para ficar `01`, `02`, `03`, etc?

Comment: Tanto no jsx, typescript ou javascript, é o mesmo procedimento.

Answer (score 9):

[`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) retorna um número. Se quer uma string, crie outra variável para receber o valor devidamente formatado:

```
const today = new Date();
const mes = today.getMonth() + 1;
let todayMonth;
if (mes < 10) {
  todayMonth = '0' + mes;
} else {
  todayMonth = mes.toString();
}
```

---

Você também pode habilitar o ES2017 (mudando para `target: "es2017"` no seu `tsconfig`), assim será possível usar [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart), que já preenche com esse zero à esquerda caso necessário:

```
const today = new Date();
let todayMonth = (today.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, 0);
```

---

Há outras respostas sugerindo usar [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) ou [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), que também funcionam (apesar de eu achar um exagero formatar a data para uma string só para fazer vários `split`'s, sendo que - na minha opinião - é bem mais simples obter o mês diretamente com `getMonth()` e formatá-lo da maneira que achar melhor).

Mas existe outra diferença fundamental: `toLocaleDateString` retorna o valor do mês de acordo com o timezone do browser (ou o que estiver configurado no node), que é consistente com `getMonth()`. Já `toISOString` retorna o mês de acordo com a data em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), que nem sempre pode ser o mesmo mês do timezone do browser (e é consistente com [`getUTCMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth)). Por exemplo, no meu browser o timezone configurado é o Horário de Brasília (no caso, o Chrome usa o do sistema operacional), então veja o que acontece com o código abaixo:

```js
let d = new Date(2019, 5, 30, 23, 0); // 30 de junho de 2019, às 23:00

// resultados obtidos em um browser cujo fuso é o Horário de Brasília
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR')); // 30/06/2019
console.log(d.toISOString()); // 2019-07-01T02:00:00.000Z
console.log(d.getMonth() + 1); // 6
console.log(d.getUTCMonth() + 1); // 7
```

<sup>Se o seu browser está configurado com um fuso horário diferente, os resultados podem variar.</sup>

A data criada corresponde a 30 de junho de 2019, às 23:00, no timezone do browser (no meu caso, no Horário de Brasília), então `toLocaleDateString` retorna `30/06/2019`. Já `toISOString` retorna esta mesma data em UTC (e 30 de junho de 2019, às 23:00 no Horário de Brasília corresponde a **1 de julho** de 2019, às 02:00 em UTC), por isso nesse caso o mês é `07`. Claro que nem sempre haverá esta diferença (durante boa parte do tempo, o mês local é o mesmo que o mês em UTC), mas dependendo do que está fazendo, é importante decidir se vai usar UTC ou o timezone do browser.

De qualquer forma, você não precisa transformar a data em uma string e fazer `split`. Se quer o mês de acordo com o timezone do browser, use `getMonth()`, mas se quer o valor em UTC, use `getUTCMonth()` - e para ambos, use uma das opções já indicadas acima (`if (valor < 10) etc..` ou `padStart`).

Answer (score 2):

É só criar uma variável só para isso, TYpeScript não é JavaScript, cada variável tem um tipo de não pode mudar, ou seja TypeScript não é bagunça:

```
let month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
let todayMonth = month.toString();
if (todayMonth < 10) todayMonth = '0' + month.toString();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/Typing.ts).

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que assim já terá o mês com o zero:

```
(new Date('Jan 05 2019'))
.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR')
.split('/')[1];
```

Você também pode obter o mês de uma data formata a partir do retorno em string, no formato ISO:

```
var dt = new Date('2019-01-10');
console.log(dt.toISOString().split('T')[0].split('-')[1]);
```

Ambas as maneiras, permitem que você receba uma data originalmente em formato brasileiro, desta maneira você não, necessariamente, precisaria acrescentar o zero quando fosse menor que 10, já que o javascript já está trazendo no formato brasileiro que você precisa, eu apenas filtrei o resultado nos casos a cima, se você deixar o `.toLocaleDateString()`vazio, ele usará o padrão do navegador do usuário, do local onde ele está.

Answer (score 2):

Assim também funciona

```
mes = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0].split('-')[1];
```

Basicamente em uma explicação passo a passo:

1. **new Date();** => *retorna um objeto Date que contem data atual juntamente com a hora;*
2. **.toISOString()** => *retorna a data no padrão iso exemplo '2019-11-05T13:31:22.753Z' , o retorno é do tipo uma string*
3. **.split('T')[0]** => *vai dividir a string cortando ela onde existe o **T**, apenas a primeira parte do corte interessa retornando **'2019-11-05'***
4. **split('-')[1]** => *vai dividir a string '2019-11-05' por **-** sendo assim apenas a segunda ocorrencia interessa, pois está é o mês*
5. **o retorno é '11' do tipo String**

---

O Mesmo codigo funciona para datas especificas

```
data = '2050-04-21T03:00:00.000Z'; // data no formato ISO
mes = new Date(data).toISOString().split('T')[0].split('-')[1]; // retorna 04
// ou mes = data.split('T')[0].split('-')[1];
```

```js
let mesAtual = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0].split('-')[1];
let mesDestaData = new Date('2050-04-21T03:00:00.000Z').toISOString().split('T')[0].split('-')[1];

console.log(mesAtual);
console.log(mesDestaData);
```